# Break role inheritance for a specific folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, administration, pnp-powershell

I want to remove all rights to a specific folder in SharePoint document library, all but a group.

So, I need to first find the folder and break inheritance on it. How to do it?

I use the following function, that searches subfolders if they have "private" name, it should break the inheritance and then set access to a specific group.

```
function RestrictFolderAccess($folderUrl) {
    Write-Output "Starting to process folders in: $folderUrl"
    $subFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderUrl -ItemType Folder -Recursive

    foreach ($folder in $subFolders) {
        Write-Output "Checking folder: $($folder.ServerRelativeUrl)"

        if ($folder.Name -eq "private" -or $folder.Name -eq "6- private") {
            Write-Output "Found target folder: $($folder.ServerRelativeUrl)"
            $folderContext = $folder.Context
            $folderContext.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields)
            $folderContext.ExecuteQuery()

            if ($null -ne $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id) {
                Write-Output "Breaking inheritance for: $($folder.ServerRelativeUrl)"
                Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "MyDocs" -Identity $folder.ListItemAllFields.Id -BreakRoleInheritance -ClearSubscopes $true
```

however, when I launch this script it says:

> Set-PnPListItemPermission : A parameter cannot be found that matches
> parameter name 'BreakRoleInheritance'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `Set-PnPFolderPermission` PnP PowerShell command instead of `Set-PnPListItemPermission`.

**Example**:

```
Set-PnPFolderPermission -List 'Shared Documents' -Identity 'Shared Documents/Folder' -User 'user@contoso.com' -AddRole 'Contribute' -ClearExisting
```

Above command adds the 'Contribute' permission to the user 'user@contoso.com' for the folder named 'Folder' located in the root of the library 'Shared Documents' and removes all other permissions.

`-ClearExisting` parameter clears all existing permissions of SharePoint document library folder.

**Documentation**: [Set-PnPFolderPermission](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPFolderPermission.html)

Comment: would the inherited permissions be removed?

Comment: Yes, using `-ClearExisting` parameter should remove it.

Comment: Hi @serge, did you try above solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: worked the variant
Set-PnPFolderPermission -List $libraryName -Identity $folder.ServerRelativeUrl -Group "MyGroup" -AddRole "Collaboration" -ClearExisting
thanks!